# ASP.net: Search 2 million (max) string returning relating data

Tags: asp.net, database, data-access

What is the best way to search a list of possibly 2 million strings, using AND / OR logic for keywords.  Each string can have up to 2 relating pieces of data.  It would be a basic database of:

name, age, children

where name is unique.

Basically I want to know what database / logic would result is the quickest full text searching.  Name is not to long, never over 255, but I need AND / OR logic, and an ability to exclude results.

If in memory is the best, thats fine and how I am doing it now, however it's becoming a pain in the bleep every time i compile it has to reload (which can take 20 seconds).  If in a database, what is my best option for this specific task?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should let the query analyser formulate it's own execution plan for this within the database engine.  You shouldn't need to worry as long as all you have is a simple select statement without any strange functions or cursors.

> however it's becoming a pain in the bleep every time i compile it has to reload (which can >take 20 seconds).

This is just the compilation of the assembly is it not?

Comment: If you load it into cache, then no, its reading a million lines from a CSV into a temporary datatable the first time you try to access it since it is not already in cache.

Comment: That changes your question considerably.  Why are you reading these into a 'cache' first time around?  A million items deserve to be in a database, why not read these in first then query the database second?

Comment: I am actually putting them in a database right now. Only reason it was not is I outsourced this to someone and that is how they choose to do it. Been about 20 hours updating his code straight, so guess i was trying to figure out why he did that =)  Thanks